# Can I reference composite key to a primary key

Tags: sqlite, syntax, foreign-keys

Here are the two tables for team and matches. I want to write COMPOSITE FOREIGN KEY reference to single primary key

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TEAM
(
    team_id integer,
    team_name text,
    PRIMARY KEY (team_id)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MATCH
(
    match_id integer,
    season_year integer,
    team1 integer,
    team2 integer,
    batted_first integer,
    batted_second integer,
    venue_name text,
    other entries

    FOREIGN KEY (team1, team2, batted_first, batted_second) 
        REFERENCES TEAM(team_id)
)
```

Is it okay to write FOREIGN KEY like this? Or do we have to write separately like

```
FOREIGN KEY (team1) REFERENCES TEAM(team_id)
FOREIGN KEY (team2) REFERENCES TEAM(team_id)
FOREIGN KEY (batted_first) REFERENCES TEAM(team_id)
FOREIGN KEY (batted_second) REFERENCES TEAM(team_id)
```

Comment: write it separately

Comment: is it like the functions in any programming language so that it must with the corresponding arguments?
i.e. FOREIGN KEY (#1, #2, #3) should match with PRIMARY KEY (@1, @2, @3)

Comment: Hi. What does your textbook intro to SQL FKs tell you about this & why is it not clear?